# Simulate multiple inheritance in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, architecture, multiple-inheritance

I have kind of an abstract class for my `UIViewControllers` (lets call it `MyViewController`) which overrides some basic methods like `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidDisappear`. In this methods some preparations are made, like setting up colors for the navigation bar, or preparing the bar buttons or something like that.

Now I want this basic behaviour for my `UITableViewControllers` also. So I made a new class that inherits `UITableViewController` (lets call it `MyTableViewController`) and copied 99% of the code from `MyViewController`.

[image: UML diagram of the current situation]

In this image you see my current architecture. Listed are the overriden methods, in which other private methods are called. Again, `MyViewController` and `MyTableViewController` share 99% codebase (only difference is the name of the class and the super class).

For obvious reasons this is crap.

Is there an elegant solution to make `MyTableViewController` a subclass of both `MyViewController` and `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one suggestion, but I don't know how useful it is because I don't know your code.

You could implement a bunch of methods in a category for the UIViewcontroller class. For example:

```
@implementation UIViewController (myCategory)
- (void)setupColors;
...
@end
```

Since both MyViewcontroller and MyTableViewcontroller inherit from UIViewController, they would inherit your methods.

The only thing that you would copy in both implementation is the invocation of those functions, but the duplicate code would be much less.

```
- viewDidLoad...
{
     [self setupColors];
}
```

Just be careful if you override methods, because you can't call [super ... ] on a category as you can in an inherited class

Comment: Well for few classes this might work. But I would have to copy/paste 50 lines per subclass. As soon as I have more than 5 subclasses There will be more code to copy with this solution.

Comment: 50 lines is not that much. Anyway, you'll realize that with any other alternative (a few of them in my mind) you'll still need to duplicate some code.

Comment: 50 lines * n subclasses = huge number imo. But thx for your effor so far.

Comment: @MarcMosby If you use a strategy pattern like what's suggested here, you should only need to add those lines to a few of the key methods and then just always subclass those. I can't think of many other view controllers that you'd subclass aside from `UITableViewController`, `UIViewController` and maybe `UICollectionViewController`. You could have your personal base class version of each of those that calls your strategy methods for things like viewDidAppear or rotation or whatever.

Comment: I wasn't getting it at first, but your solution makes perfect sense now. Thanks @JasonCoco and Merlevede.

Comment: Most of the refactoring went fine, but I am having trouble with shared properties. I added a UIViewController extension to my category with the needed properties, but I am getting *unrecognized selector* at runtime.

Comment: I got that solved, I had to declare the properties both in my *abstract* classes and my category.

Answer (score 1):

Shared implementation for your common methods could be done either with a category or with composition. Since a category can't be used to directly override existing interface (e.g. viewDidLoad:) you would need to put your private methods into the category and call them from your subclass overrides. Another option would be to put your shared implementation in a separate class (which might be a singleton) and compose an instance of that as a property of both MyViewController and MyTableViewController, e.g.:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyControllerStyler *controllerStyler;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [controllerStyler viewDidLoad];
}
...etc...
```

The composed class's methods could reference the controller if needed, e.g.:

```
@interface MyControllerStyler : NSObject

- (void)viewDidLoadInController: (UIViewController *)controller;
...etc...
```

While a category seems perfectly fine for this example, if your extensions collectively represent a meaningful unit of your design (such as a collection of visual styling attributes) that might argue for a separate object (or objects) to better represent your intent.